# Using foreach for displaying multiple emails from a serialized data to array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an multiple email input field, when i submit this form i'm serializing the datas and making Ajax call.
When i'm in my treatment.php i can have access to my email list by accessing `$_POST['emailAddress']`
so thats displaying my email addresses. 
Now i need to use a `Foreach` to make some actions with those emails but i can't use that foreach on that string.
How sould I proceed? 
Thx

My foreach :

```
foreach ($adresses as $adresse){
         //actions to do;
    }
```

Comment: Use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to turn the string into an array.

Comment: Can you give the code for how does the $addresses seems like ?

Comment: What's the data look like?

Comment: ok guys thats fine the solution of @Elisha Senoo worked for me thats nice ! Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys thats fine the 
`$adresses = explode(",", $adresses);` 
worked for me
Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

If separator is comma (,) then you can do

```
$emails = explode(',', $_POST['emailAddress']);

foreach ($emails as $email) {
// do something
}
```

if you have other separator just change it in `explode`

Comment: how do you first know $_POST['emailAddress'] ia a coma seperated value ?

Comment: I said if it is comma, he can do it this way I believe it is comma or this is json string therefore, we go with `$emails = json_decode($_POST['emailAddress']);`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply explode the string by the delimiter used (e.g comma):

```
foreach (explode(",", $adresses) as $adresse){
         //actions to do;
    }
```

Comment: how do you first know $_POST['emailAddress'] ia a coma seperated value

Comment: You have a point there. I just assumed that was the case. But it is usually so.